# z-index MGLAnnotationView mapbox IOS

Tags: mapbox-ios

Is it possible to manage z-index of MGLAnnotationView in iOs? [The yellow and green annotations are supposed to be over blue ones in the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRPyc.png). I add the annotation view in this way :

```
var annotationView = mapView2.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
if annotationView == nil {
    annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    switch reuseIdentifier {
    case "NP" :
        let animageView = UIImageView(image: imageGreen)
        annotationView?.addSubview(animageView)

        //annotationView?.bringSubview(toFront: annotationView!)
            break

 (...)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The z-index can be set using the following line of code:

```
annotationView?.layer.zPosition = 3
```

the higher the number is, the closer it is to the user